After authentication and later followed by a first request a new CSRF token is not sent back as a response
I'm using spring security
I after authorization I use the X-XSRF-TOKEN return header info as the XSRF token for the next request

the next request where I copy the  X-XSRF-TOKEN return header into the post X-XSRF-TOKEN header

but unlike the authorization I get the same X-XSRF-TOKEN header value as a return when I send the post ... and every other request is denied

does this mean I need to make two of the same requests ... because I do c a new cookery value generated with the new token.
I am new to spring security can anyone help
